# NSDictionary Create Error, Some key no quote

Tags: ios, objective-c

Create a Dictionary

[image: Create a Dictionary]

Print result:

[image: print result]

I can't get it with key, `valueForKey: @"userPhone"`
why userPhone no quote

Comment: i use xcode10 on macOS10.14

Comment: I wouldn't get hung up on the console output, I've never understood how it picks and chooses when to wrap a string in quotes or not. Calling `[dict valueForKey: @"userPhone"]` should work fine though based off of what you've shared. Is that not working?

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC.

Comment: It would help if you actually show us the actual error if there is an error. The image just shows the log with no quotes which as @Philzay81 mentioned is no problem. I tried logging the same dictionary with strings and none of my values have quotes.

Comment: @vadian ths,but i use dict[@"userPhone"] still wrong, maybe a xcode bug.

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem in Xcode 10 and OSX 10.14.

```
        NSDictionary * dict = @{
                                @"userPhone": @"123",
                                @"userName": @"123"
                                };
        NSLog(@"%@",dict.description);
        NSLog(@"%@", [dict valueForKey: @"userPhone"]);
```